# Does TFLiteConverter automatically quantize the Keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, quantization

I converted the trained Keras model using tf.lite.TFLiteConverter into tflite_model. Is the converted tflite_model quantized one? Here is the snippet to make the conversion.

```
import tensorflow as tf

keras_model = "./Trained_Models/h_vs_o_a_V1.h5"

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Comment: To enable model quantization, we need to add the following flag ~> `converter.post_training_quantize = True`

Comment: Where do I insert the code? Is it before tflite_model = converter.convert() ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, we need the `converter.post_training_quantize = True` flag before the conversion takes place using `converter.convert()` like,

```
import tensorflow as tf

keras_model = "./Trained_Models/h_vs_o_a_V1.h5"

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_model)
converter.post_training_quantize = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```